# Doctrine2: Syncing Collections / Adding multiple Elements of which some might already exist

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

So i have a string, representing several objects (tags in this case)
i.e.: "php,mysql,doctrine2"
Let's say my database already has "php" and "doctrine2".
Now i want the best way to add the missing elemets (in this case mysql).

Should i create an object for every element and just use persist/sync or something, or is there a better way?

I need all the objects at the end anyway to add them to a new object (with a simple many-to-many relation) anyway.

I'd be happy about any suggestions.

Comment: 1) Find all existing tags with one query by tags 2) Find out with a loop which aren't in the result 3) Create and persist missing objects 4) create another array with all objects and set it as tags. What is the problem?

Comment: @meze: The Problem is that it seems like a lot to do for a common/simple task. I thought there might be a more smart "merge" option to do this, having collections and entity states and such.

Comment: There's cascade persist that you can set for relations to skip persisting each object manually. But you still need an array of merged existing tags and newly created ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Pull out all your tag names with a single query into an array

2) Use array_filter along with a closure to detect tags not present in the dataset

3) Create an insert for the new tags

```
$currentTags = getCurrentTagsArray();
$newTags = explode(',', 'php,mysql,doctrine2');

$newTagsToSave = array_filter($currentTags, function($item) use ($newTags){
    if (in_array($item, $newTags))
    {
       return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

Or...

You can use Doctrine 2's ArrayCollection wrapper (\Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection()) it has pretty much the same implementation above as a filter method (you still need to pass the closure).

```
$myCollection->filter($closure);
```

Comment: Thanks! That is already a lot better and easier than what i did before.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where I had to synchronize an entity collection with an external source.  However, my problem  required not only additions, but also updates and deletes.  I used code to diff the ArrayCollection with another array, and call CRUD methods add based on the differences.  As far as I can tell from the docs, doctrine doesn't natively handle this.  Average performance should be  O(n) but takes some memory.

```
/**
 * @param array $source - the array we are starting with
 * @param array $new - the array we want to end with
 * @param $fnHash - function used to determine object equality, not based on object id
 * @param $fnUpdate - function to perform update of existing object, takes current object and new object as params
 * @param $fnAdd - function to perform insert
 * @param $fnDelete - function to perform delete
 */
public static function syncArrays(array $source, array $new,
        $fnHash, $fnUpdate, $fnAdd, $fnDelete)
{
    // make modifiable array copies mapped by hashes of the elements

    $sourceKeys = array_map($fnHash, $source);
    $hasKeys =count($sourceKeys) > 0;
    $newarray = ($hasKeys) ? array_combine(array_map($fnHash, $new), $new) : $new;
    if ($hasKeys) { // true => may have updates or deletes
        $sourcearray = array_combine($sourceKeys, $source);

        // updates
        foreach ($sourceKeys as $hashkey) {
            if (isset($sourcearray[$hashkey]) && isset($newarray[$hashkey])) {
                $fnUpdate($sourcearray[$hashkey], $newarray[$hashkey]);
                unset($sourcearray[$hashkey]);
                unset($newarray[$hashkey]);
            }
        }


        // deletes
        foreach ($sourcearray as $entity) {
            $fnDelete($entity);
        }
    }
    //adds
    foreach ($newarray as $entity) {
        $fnAdd($entity);
    }
}
```

The way I call it to update my doctrine association $parentEntity->getPayments()  is:

```
ArrayHelper::syncArrays($parentEntity->getPayments()->toArray(), $newPayments,
    function($entity) {return $a->getName();}, // hash function
    function($current, $new) {
        $current->setTotal($new->getTotal()); // update function
    },
    function($a) use ($parent, $manager) {
        $parent->addVendorPaymentObject($a);  // add function
        $manager->persist($a);
    },
    function($a) use ($manager) {  // delete function
        $manager->remove($a);
    }
);
```